# Latest Google Play Game Service Plugin For Unity Not Working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have started using Google Play Game Services plugin for unity lately in my game Dodgy for android and the plugin doesn't seem to work!

I have tried following what they say on GitHub installed all the necessary tools and plugins and it still doesn't work, What exactly happens is when I start my app and try to sign in nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

The Tools I Use...

- Latest Android Studio as of today with all plugins and tools installed
- Unity 2018.3b7
- The latest version of Visual Studio 2017*
- The latest GPGS plugin on GitHub*

Comment: There's a fix for this bug present on GitHub. Use the following link: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1947#issuecomment-422770633

Answer (score 2):

Steps to check.

- Make sure you are using signed APK
- Make sure you have published your game on Google Play Services.(The place where you created leaderboards & achievements)
- Check SHA1 for your KeyStore file & compare it with Google Developer Console's SHA1 for that project.

Comment: Use this & check your log runtime to get more details of the error. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/log-viewer-12047

Comment: Oh! It gives me this two errors may you help me with them...

1st  - https://ibb.co/iTvMVq
2nd - https://ibb.co/cPetbV

Comment: You need to resolve dependencies. Go to **Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android > Force Resolve.** If this option is not there then install this plugin https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Comment: It's there and everything is resolved but now, The app crashes whenever I call `Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {  });`

Comment: Okay, I found a solution for the crash here (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1947#issuecomment-422770633)

Comment: I also knew this solution, but I just forgot it when writing this answer.

Comment: No problem you still helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found what I did wrong. If you have confirmed that your package has been properly signed but still not working. Look back in your code.

If you use the plugin(most likely), you need to use **PlayGamesPlatform** namespace functions other than the **Social** ones.

Or the Play Games login won't even pop, yet it does pop if you check Development Build which would be confusing. Hope this would save time for those who come after me